# Unable to select range for copying

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

The behaviour of my excel (2007) changed today, maybe I’ve changed some setting without noticing.
I have a column of values, some values, some formulae.  The first cell is a figure (say 100 as an example).
I select first cell and then drag down the little + at the bottom right of first cell to highlight and select the range.  Normally I just then drag this sideways as many columns as needed to copy the range.
Now, it isn’t selecting the first column range. Instead it is copying the first cell (the 100) down into all the cells in the column.
I’ve been using excel since it was created but very little since I retired a few years ago.  Have I just forgotten how to select a range or have I overwritten some setting?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Could you edit your post and include a screenshot of what you're starting with and what you want to have at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am not using Excel 2007, so if what I am writing is incorrect, don't hesitate to correct me.

I think, based on your description, what you are doing is this:

[image]

When using the + at the bottom right of the cell, you copy the cell instead of selecting a range. What you should try is selecting the cell directly with the big white +. Then, you can use the small + (on the bottom right of the last cell of the range to drag and copy to other cells/columns.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  It is operator error.